# Mongod runs, but Mongo returns an error

Tags: mongodb

This question has been asked before but was never answered.  Furthermore, my error logs are slightly different:

When I run 'mongo' I get this error:

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.2.0
connecting to: test
Fri Nov 16 10:52:05 Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:91
exception: connect failed
```

Here are my error logs:

```
Fri Nov 16 10:47:44 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=46508 port=27017     dbpath=/usr/local/var/mongodb 64-bit host=Brians-MacBook-Pro-2.local
Fri Nov 16 10:47:44 [initandlisten] 
Fri Nov 16 10:47:44 [initandlisten] ** WARNING: soft rlimits too low. Number of files is 256, should be at least 1000
Fri Nov 16 10:47:44 [initandlisten] db version v2.2.0, pdfile version 4.5
Fri Nov 16 10:47:44 [initandlisten] git version: f5e83eae9cfbec7fb7a071321928f00d1b0c5207
Fri Nov 16 10:47:44 [initandlisten] build info: Darwin bs-osx-106-x86-64-1.local 10.8.0 Darwin Kernel Version 10.8.0: Tue Jun  7 16:33:36 PDT 2011; root:xnu-1504.15.3~1/RELEASE_I386 i386 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
Fri Nov 16 10:47:44 [initandlisten] options: { bind_ip: "127.0.0.1", config: "/usr/local/etc/mongod.conf", dbpath: "/usr/local/var/mongodb", logappend: "true", logpath: "/usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log" }
Fri Nov 16 10:47:44 [initandlisten] journal dir=/usr/local/var/mongodb/journal
Fri Nov 16 10:47:44 [initandlisten] recover begin
Fri Nov 16 10:47:44 [initandlisten] couldn't open /usr/local/var/mongodb/journal/lsn errno:13 Permission denied
Fri Nov 16 10:47:44 [initandlisten]   Assertion failure f.is_open() src/mongo/db/dur_journal.cpp 552
0x10037637b 0x1000b0196 0x100105ec2 0x10049de46 0x10049e445 0x10049e628 0x1002401ac     0x1000057ec 0x10000608d 0x10000d534 0x10000f309 0x100000ea4 0x3 
 0   mongod                              0x000000010037637b _ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo + 43
 1   mongod                              0x00000001000b0196 _ZN5mongo12verifyFailedEPKcS1_j + 310
 2   mongod                              0x0000000100105ec2 _ZN5mongo3dur14journalReadLSNEv + 898
 3   mongod                              0x000000010049de46 _ZN5mongo3dur11RecoveryJob2goERSt6vectorIN5boost11filesystem210basic_pathISsNS4_11path_traitsEEESaIS7_EE + 86
 4   mongod                              0x000000010049e445 _ZN5mongo3dur8_recoverEv + 405
 5   mongod                              0x000000010049e628 _ZN5mongo3dur7recoverEv + 40
 6   mongod                              0x00000001002401ac _ZN5mongo3dur7startupEv + 124
 7   mongod                              0x00000001000057ec _ZN5mongo14_initAndListenEi + 1052
 8   mongod                              0x000000010000608d _ZN5mongo13initAndListenEi + 29
 9   mongod                              0x000000010000d534 _ZL11mongoDbMainiPPc + 29348
 10  mongod                              0x000000010000f309 main + 9
 11  mongod                              0x0000000100000ea4 start + 52
 12  ???                                 0x0000000000000003 0x0 + 3
Fri Nov 16 10:47:44 [initandlisten] dbexception during recovery: 13611 can't read lsn file in journal directory : assertion src/mongo/db/dur_journal.cpp:552
Fri Nov 16 10:47:44 [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 13611 can't read lsn file in journal directory : assertion src/mongo/db/dur_journal.cpp:552, terminating
Fri Nov 16 10:47:44 dbexit: 
Fri Nov 16 10:47:44 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
Fri Nov 16 10:47:44 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
Fri Nov 16 10:47:44 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close sockets...
Fri Nov 16 10:47:44 [initandlisten] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
Fri Nov 16 10:47:44 [initandlisten] shutdown: lock for final commit...
Fri Nov 16 10:47:44 [initandlisten] shutdown: final commit...
Fri Nov 16 10:47:44 [initandlisten] shutdown: closing all files...
Fri Nov 16 10:47:44 [initandlisten] closeAllFiles() finished
Fri Nov 16 10:47:44 [initandlisten] shutdown: removing fs lock...
Fri Nov 16 10:47:44 dbexit: really exiting now
```

There is no output when I run:

```
netstat -f inet -a -n | grep 27101
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Weird... it works when I run mongod in one tab and then open a second tab and run the mongo client. Why would this be the case???

Answer (score 3):

As @Nilam said one of your problems is the journal, however, you actually have two problems here, the one I am talking about being more of a warning:

```
Fri Nov 16 10:47:44 [initandlisten] ** WARNING: soft rlimits too low. Number of files is 256, should be at least 1000
```

This specifically relates to: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-4407

You should look into increasing your openfile count in Linux otherwise you could get this: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Too+Many+Open+Files of course this page also tells you how to solve the problem.

NB: as a side note to the journal point, it looks like your MongoDB node could be trying to recover from something. I would check why.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to @Hartator's answer, this solved the issue for me:

```
chmod -R 777 /data/db
```

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
journal dir=/usr/local/var/mongodb/journal
```

The error shows is

```
[initandlisten] couldn't open /usr/local/var/mongodb/journal/lsn errno:13 Permission denied
```

So check if journal directory exist and proper write permissions are given to this folder.

Comment: Hi Nilam, Thanks for your response. everything should be fine with this folder. here's the permissions: `-rwxrwxrwx  1 root  admin  88 Sep 29 10:38 lsn`

Comment: Are you running MongoDB as root/admin? If you installed from repos most likely the user is actually `mongod` or `mongodb` I would check what user you run mongod as, also we dunno if you are running as service or straight in command prompt, which way are you running it?

Answer (score -2):

Try to run :

```
chmod 777 -R /usr/local/var/mongodb
```

Comment: i get:   ' No such file or directory '

Comment: though I can naviagate to that folder which contains:   journal  mongod.lock test.0  test.1  test.ns