# I can start the MongoDB shell, but not Mongo Daemon

Tags: mongodb

I'm new to MongoDB, and I'm trying to run `mongod`. If I type in `mongo`, I can run the shell (and then I exit nicely with ^C), but when I try typing `mongod`, I get this:

```
mongod --help for help and startup options
Sat Nov 24 13:42:34 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=99910 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db/ 64-bit host=Macbook-err.local
Sat Nov 24 13:42:34 [initandlisten] 
Sat Nov 24 13:42:34 [initandlisten] ** WARNING: soft rlimits too low. Number of files is 256, should be at least 1000
Sat Nov 24 13:42:34 [initandlisten] db version v2.2.1, pdfile version 4.5
Sat Nov 24 13:42:34 [initandlisten] git version: nogitversion
Sat Nov 24 13:42:34 [initandlisten] build info: Darwin 172-26-13-128.dynapool.nyu.edu 12.2.0 Darwin Kernel Version 12.2.0: Sat Aug 25 00:48:52 PDT 2012; root:xnu-2050.18.24~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
Sat Nov 24 13:42:34 [initandlisten] options: {}
Sat Nov 24 13:42:34 [initandlisten] journal dir=/data/db/journal
Sat Nov 24 13:42:34 [initandlisten] recover : no journal files present, no recovery needed
Sat Nov 24 13:42:34 [websvr] ERROR: listen(): bind() failed errno:48 Address already in use for socket: 0.0.0.0:28017
Sat Nov 24 13:42:34 [websvr] ERROR:   addr already in use
Sat Nov 24 13:42:34 [initandlisten] ERROR: listen(): bind() failed errno:48 Address already in use for socket: 0.0.0.0:27017
Sat Nov 24 13:42:34 [initandlisten] ERROR:   addr already in use
Sat Nov 24 13:42:34 [initandlisten] now exiting
Sat Nov 24 13:42:34 dbexit: 
Sat Nov 24 13:42:34 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
Sat Nov 24 13:42:34 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
Sat Nov 24 13:42:34 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close sockets...
Sat Nov 24 13:42:34 [initandlisten] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
Sat Nov 24 13:42:34 [initandlisten] shutdown: lock for final commit...
Sat Nov 24 13:42:34 [initandlisten] shutdown: final commit...
Sat Nov 24 13:42:34 [initandlisten] shutdown: closing all files...
Sat Nov 24 13:42:34 [initandlisten] closeAllFiles() finished
Sat Nov 24 13:42:34 [initandlisten] journalCleanup...
Sat Nov 24 13:42:34 [initandlisten] removeJournalFiles
Sat Nov 24 13:42:34 [initandlisten] shutdown: removing fs lock...
Sat Nov 24 13:42:34 dbexit: really exiting now
```

This seems to be a common problem around here, and I've tried:
deleting the mongod.lock file `rm /data/db/mongod.lock`
repair: `mongod --repair`
killing processes: `killall -15 mongod` and `killall -9 mongod`
I tried changing permissions: `sudo chmod 0755 /data/db` and `sudo chown $USER /data/db`

My permissions seem correct:

```
drwxr-xr-x  4 slaffont  wheel  136 Nov 24 13:28 /data/db/
```

I've run out of ideas. Has anyone else had this problem? What should I do? :(

Comment: Are you sure you dont have some other app running on the same port? Or another instance of mongod as a daemon? Sometimes if you have a service set up and you kill it, the process manager will just start it again.

Comment: Also run:  "lsof -i :27017" , to see what is running on that port

Comment: Thanks for helping! I ran `lsof -i :27017` and nothing came up :\

Comment: Does anything come up when you grep for mongo? "ps aux | grep mongo"

Comment: Yes, this is what comes up: http://cl.ly/image/3R0P383Y0E2O
As I mentioned below, if I run mongod on a different port, it works! Still, would like to know what's wrong with 27017, if anyone has any ideas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your main comments, it seems you installed MongoDB via macports (given the /opt install location). What I believe might be happening is that the recipe for macports installed MongoDB as a launchd service.

Check this location for a mongodb related plist file: `/Library/LaunchDaemons`
If you find it, that means your system will automatically keep this service running. If you only want to run the mongod manually, then remove this plist and reboot. Or you can try this command:
`launchctl unload /Library/LaunchDaemons/path.to.mongo.plist`

Otherwise, run another instance of mongod on a different port.

Comment: Yes! There it is: `org.macports.mongodb.plist` Awesome! Thank you so much. If I wasn't such a n00b, I'd upvote you. Thanks @jdi and @shelman for your help!

Answer (score 2):

sudo rm /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock 
sudo chown -R mongodb:mongodb /var/lib/mongodb/ 
sudo -u mongodb mongod -f /etc/mongodb.conf --repair 
sudo service mongodb start 
or instead of the last one try : sudo mongod

Answer (score 1):

"Address already in use for socket: 0.0.0.0:28017"

It looks like mongo is already running or another process is using port 27017

In this case, type the following command

```
ps wuax | grep mongo
```

You should see something that looks like this

```
User           31936   0.5 0.4 2719784 35624   ?? S     7:34pm   0:09.98 mongod
User           31945   0.0 0.0 2423368   184 s000 R+   8:24pm   0:00.00 grep mongo
```

Now enter the kill command for the mongod instance (31936 in this case):

```
kill 31936
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like something is already bound to port 27017, making it seem like another `mongod` is running (that was not killed on the `killall`).  Does the output of `ps aux` or `lsof -i :27017` show any mongod processes running?

If this proves completely fruitless, you can always pass the `--port <portnum>` option to the `mongod` process via the command line, telling it to listen on a different port (use the same option for the `mongo` shell to tell it to connect on a different port than 27017.

Comment: Thanks @shelman! I tried `lsof -i :27017` and nothing came up. I tried `ps aux | grep mongod` and I get this: http://cl.ly/image/3R0P383Y0E2O  
But, I did try running mongod with a different port and it worked! I'd like to know what's wrong with 27017, though, if anyone has any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

As @shelman said, you already have something using that port, however your command to understand if something is running is wrong, try:

```
sudo netstat -lpn |grep :27017
```

I have noticed as well:

```
Sat Nov 24 13:42:34 [initandlisten] ** WARNING: soft rlimits too low. Number of files is 256, should be at least 1000
```

This is more of an warning but still one you should heed. I answered a question with some one who had this problem recently: [Mongod runs, but Mongo returns an error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13420073/mongod-runs-but-mongo-returns-an-error/13420338#13420338) that should help.

Answer (score 0):

Since this seems to be a common question:

As someone who just had/solved this problem, what you're probably running into is this. When you first install Mongo (say, via apt-get), the Mongod process automatically starts running. For example:

**terekhov / $** sudo apt-get install mongodb-10gen 
--Snip Install Process-- 
Done. mongodb
start/running, process 4467 
Processing triggers for ureadahead ...
**terekhov / $** service mongodb start start: Job is already running: mongodb

So, if you don't need a [forked daemon](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/manage-mongodb-processes/) etc, then just type `mongo` to start the command shell; it will automatically search for a MongoDB daemon on port 27017. Happily, that's where ours is.

You can [start/stop/restart](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/) the mongod process with this command: `sudo service mongodb stop`